# Git Installation on OSX: Cannot exec 'git-credential-osxkeychain': Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: macos, git, github, i386

I am attempting to follow the directions on https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git for getting up and running with git.  I installed version 1.8.4.2.

However when I try to use the OS X Keychain Helper I get:

> fatal: cannot exec 'git-credential-osxkeychain': Bad CPU type in executable

I am using an older but still Intel MBP (Intel Core Duo), which is 32 bit and it looks like the binary is x86_64 only. The main git binary from the same package is compiled for both i386 and x86_64.

So it looks like the current package is not fully i386 compatible, and since I am very new to git I guess the question becomes are there any other ways to cache my password besides this helper?  It is described as the recommended way moving forwards.

Answer (score 0):

"I get build errors when trying to build that helper universally. You'll just have to remove it for the time being."

from: https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/issues/detail?id=97

It's a wontfix issue.

Comment: Yep, saw that.  I guess I can see why it is not considered worth fixing, but it seems kinda odd that the rest of the binaries are compiled for both architectures but that helper is not.

Comment: Definitely odd to me too, for what it's worth :-)